# SwiftUI observedobject with dynamic fields

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI. I have an object that has various properties that I want to bind to fields in the UI. However, the UI is dynamically created. As in, the fields to include and what order can be customized.

Having trouble getting the UI to refresh when the object is updated (for example, when the user enters a zip code, we automatically populate the city and state fields) I have created a simplified sample.

I can get it to work by handling each individual field when creating the `TextField`, but would like to see if it is possible to be more generic.

Here is the sample object that the UI is displaying the properties

```
class TestObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var testForeignKeyId: Int = 0
    @Published var city: String = ""
    @Published var state: String = ""
    @Published var zip: String = ""
    
    func getStringValue(field: String) -> String {
        switch field {
        case "City":
            return self.city
        case "State":
            return self.state
        case "Zip":
            return self.zip
        default:
            return ""
        }
    }
    
    func getIntValue(field: String) -> Int {
        switch field {
        case "TestForeignKeyId":
            return self.testForeignKeyId
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

Sample field struct:

```
struct TestField: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    var label: String
    var fieldType: String
}
```

It works if I do this and handle each field:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var obj: TestObject
    var fields: [TestField] = []
    @State var stringValue = ""
    
    init() {
        self.fields = [TestField(label: "City", fieldType: "Text"), TestField(label: "State", fieldType: "Text"), TestField(label: "Zip", fieldType: "Zip")]
        self.obj = TestObject()
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.fields) { field in
                Text(field.label)
                switch field.label {
                case "City":
                    TextField("", text: $obj.city)
                case "State":
                    TextField("", text: $obj.state)
                case "Zip":
                    TextField("", text: $obj.zip,
                              onEditingChanged: { edit in
                                if !edit {
                                    // lookup values for zip
                                    self.obj.city = "Test"
                                    self.obj.state = "TT"
                                }
                              })
                default:
                    Text(field.label)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Would like to be able to do something like this and create the text fields based on the `fieldtype` instead of the individual fields (since the actual object has many more properties):

```
                switch field.fieldType {
                case "Text":
                    Text(field.label)
                    TextField("", text: self.obj.getStringValue(field: field.label))
                case "Zip":
                    Text(field.label)
                    TextField("", text: self.obj.getStringValue(field: field.label))

                }
```

But when I do that, I get the error:

Cannot convert value of type `String` to expected argument type `Binding<String>`

I also tried using a state variable like

`@State var stringValue = ""`

Then in the .onAppear of the text field, I assigned the value of the appropriate property (`obj.state` etc) to the `stringValue` state variable. I thought that maybe the control would refresh if the `observedObject` was updated, but couldn't figure out where to update the `stringValue` state variable to get it working.

Hopefully I explained what I'm trying to do well enough. Does anyone have an idea on how to get it working?

Thanks

Comment: As the error says, you need a binding (`@Published`, `@State` or `@Binding` property).  A computed property or function value can't be a binding.  With a binding, SwiftUI observes the property and automatically updates the UI when the property changes.  In your second code block there is nothing to tell SwiftUI to update the view when, say, `zip`, changes.  You would probably need to change your `TestField` object so that it accepts a binding and you can then use that binding in the `TextField` - `TestField(label: "City", fieldType: "Text", fieldValue: $obj.zip)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem with `getStringValue(field: String)` function is that it returns a `String` value (constant) while SwiftUI `TextField` View takes a `Binding` for its `text` parameter.

So, `SwiftUI` is throwing that error because it's not able to convert automatically a `String` value to a `Binding` of that string.
One way to solve this is to move your `getStringValue(field: String)` function into your `ContentView` and instead of returning a `String`, you should return a `Binding` of the string.

So, the function would look like this:

```
func getStringValue(field: String) -> Binding<String> {
    switch field {
    case "City":
        return self.$obj.city
    case "State":
        return self.$obj.state
    case "Zip":
        return self.$obj.zip
    default:
        return .constant("")
    }
}
```

At this point, you should not have that error again and the code should compile correctly.

Of course, you can still improve this by using a `Struct` and `enum` instead of a `hard-coded` string values.

Comment: In addition to the above, I've tried to demonstrate how you could use enum and struct to achieve the same result .Check out this gist: [SwiftUIdynamicfields](https://gist.github.com/cedricbahirwe/2fd2b9e8e465675920fb26a80e4a4f7b)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was very helpful.